# Load Balancer Service type in azure VM

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I have created a Kubernetes cluster ( 1 master, 2 workers VMs) using kubeadm on Azure. Node type service is working as expected. But Load Balancer service type is not working.

I have created the public IP address in azure and attached this IP to the service. I could see IP Address is attached for the service but this IP address is not accessible from outside.

And I have created the load balancer in Azure and attached the load balancer public IP address to the service that I have created in azure. This option also didn't work.

Just curious to know how to configure Load Balancer Service type in azure VM.

I have tried with aks and it worked with out any issues.

Comment: is that you are looking for : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-load-balancer-standard-public-portal

Comment: Did you add some additional configuration to make LoadBalancer service type working on kubeadm on Azure? If yes, could you provide tutorial that you used? What CNI plugin are you using? Could you share yaml configuration files that are you applied? Please add missing information to your question

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT I am not looking for How to create load balancer in azure? I am looking for how to configure load balancer service in azure vm Kubernetes configured using kubeadm

Comment: @QuentinMerlin I am NOT able to configure LoadBalancer service type. I just tried with basic example of nginx deployment and attaching the public IP to nginx  Load Balancer service. There were no errors. But the public ip is not accessible from outside. I am looking for a help how  to configure LoadBalancer service on Azure kubernetes which is configured using kubeadm

Comment: This you may refer : https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2021/10/29/setting-up-kubernetes-on-azure-using-kubeadm/

Comment: Hey @stackissuefinder had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT No. Thanks for the update. I am looking for how to configure Load Balancer Service Type in Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm on Azure (NOT AKS). These are configured using (1 master, 2 workers VMs) and kubeadm. If you could help me on this that would be great.

Comment: @stackissuefinder, would suggest you to please refer this link for creating the required AKS infrastructure as required: - https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2021/10/29/setting-up-kubernetes-on-azure-using-kubeadm/  It may be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please follow the steps as given by me below for creating an AKS cluster in Azure and attaching a load balancer to that AKS cluster with a public IP for the front end for it. The steps for doing the said should be as below: -

a)  Firstly, execute the below command in **Azure CLI in Azure BASH cloud shell**. The below creates an AKS cluster with `two nodes in it of type ‘Linux’ with a ‘Standard’ load balancer` in the said resource group where the **‘VM set type’ should be set as ‘VirtualMachineScaleSets’ with the appropriate version of Kubernetes** being specified in it: -

```
 az aks create \
--resource-group <resource group name>\
--name <AKS cluster name> \
--vm-set-type <VMSS or Availability set> \
--node-count <node count> \
--generate-ssh-keys \
--kubernetes-version <version number> \
--load-balancer-sku <basic or standard SKU>
```

Sample command: -

```
 az aks create \
--resource-group AKSrg  \
--name AKStestcluster \
--vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets \
--node-count 2 \
--generate-ssh-keys \
--kubernetes-version 1.16.8 \
--load-balancer-sku standard
```

I would suggest you to please use the below command to `check the installed version of Kubernetes orchestrator` in your Azure BASH cloud shell **according to the region specified and use the appropriate version** in the above command: -

```
  az aks get-versions --location eastus --output table
```

Then, I would suggest you use the below command for **getting credentials of the AKS cluster** created: -

```
   az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource group name> --name <AKS cluster name>
```

b)  Then execute the below command for **getting the information of the created nodes**: -

```
  kubectl get nodes
```

Once the information is fetched, then load the **appropriate ‘YAML’ files** in the AKS cluster and apply them to be run as an application on them. Then, `check the service state` as below: -

```
 kubectl get service <application service name> --watch
```

c)  Then press **‘Ctrl+C’**, after `noting the public IP address of the load balancer`. Then execute the below command for **setting the managed outbound public IP for the AKS cluster** and the configured load balancer: -

```
az aks update \
--resource-group myResourceGroup \
--name myAKSCluster \
--load-balancer-managed-outbound-ip-count 1 ’
```

This will ensure that the services running in the back end will have only one public IP in the front end. In this way, you will be able to create an AKS cluster with load balancer having a public IP address.